# Java Regular Expression throwing error

Tags: java, regex, perl

I am trying to capture a certain number chunk from within a text. Suppose the text is **Kane is 12345 feet high**. I want to capture `12345`. I am trying to use this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
String text = "Kane is 12345 feet high";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Kane is (\\d+) feet high");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
String s0 = m.group(0);
```

However I am getting a `Match not found` error. What am I doing wrong here? I mean, in Perl, this perfectly prints out `12345`:

```
$foo = "Kane is 12345 feet high";
$foo =~ /Kane is (\d+) feet high/;
print $1;
```

Comment: You need to use `matches` for an exact match of the whole regex or `find` to find the regex in a sub-string.  Unfortunately it doesn't give you a more useful error like `Match not found, did you forget to call matches() or find()` ;)

Comment: Also reading the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) is actually a good practice for a programmer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to invoke Matcher.find() before calling Matcher.group()

```
String text = "Kane is 12345 feet high";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Kane is (\\d+) feet high");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if(m.find()){
String s0 = m.group(0);

}
```

> Suppose the text is Kane is 12345 feet high. I want to capture 12345

i think, your Regex should be like below in order to just capture the number in your text.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

Comment: No, only `\d+` won't suffice, for there may be numeric chunks in **Kane** as well, like **Kane142**..So in that case I will need to capture the 2nd group.

Comment: @Cupidvogel ohk.. i tought you only needed literal digits, :P

Comment: Yeah, that would look like it from my question..:P

Answer (score 8):

Just instantiating `Matcher` isn't enough: you must call `m.matches()` and the standard practice would be to put it in an if:

```
if (m.matches()) s0 = m.group(1);
```

Comment: +1, but I think you should be using `group(1)`, not `group(0)`.  I know the OP used `group(0)`, but he also said he was trying to extract the number.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
public static String stripNonDigits(final String input){
  final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
    final char c = input.charAt(i);
    if(c > 47 && c < 58){
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

}
  Test Code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
final String input = "0-123-abc-456-xyz-789";
final String result = stripNonDigits(input);
System.out.println(result);
 }
```

Output:

0123456789

Might be helpfull thanks

Comment: I'm sure that works fine, but it doesn't answer the question.  What the OP wants to know is why his own code doesn't work.